# Regular Expression (Regex) for pulling name between quotations - Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have strings that look as follows:

```
\\.\ROOT\abc\kjasdkj\MyClass:InstanceName.name="sxs-test3"
```

I want a regex that can only pull out the name in quotations so the result is `sxs-test3`

Also, I am using windows Powershell to do this, can this be done in PowerShell?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($subject -cmatch '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")') {
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```

This looks for any number of characters except quotes (`[^"]*`), but only if they are preceded by a quote (`(?<=")`) and followed by a quote (`(?=")`).

It does not even try to handle escaped quotes.

Comment: Wouldn't `if ($subject -match '"([^"]*)"') {$result = $matches[1]}` suffice?

Comment: using this online tool, I don't see your regex working @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: I see because it is second element of matches list. That is powershell specific . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option that doesn't require regex:

```
$path.TrimEnd('"').Split('="',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[-1]
```

Comment: This will only work correctly if the string ends with the double-quoted term, though.

Comment: Works for me even if the name is not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: In my tests it extracted `bar` from `foo"bar"`, but `baz` from `foo"bar"baz`.

Comment: I was testing against ...="..." and ...=..., in any case the equal sign is required.

Comment: I like that one too. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For that string this regex seems simplest to me:

```
$string = '\\.\ROOT\abc\kjasdkj\MyClass:InstanceName.name="sxs-test3"'

if ($string  -match '"(.+?)"') {
    $Matches[1]
}
```

Matches everything inside double quotes as few times as possible (lazy expansion).